# Java Script error

Tags: java, jsp

i Have the below mentioned java script code but it is showing syntax error with else token ,i dont understand what is going wrong

```
<% if (isAliveMessage=="TIVOLI ALARM") {%>
<FONT COLOR="Red">
<p><b>Status of Alarm:<%= isAliveMessage  %></b></p>
</FONT>
<% } %>
<% else {%>
<p><b>Status of Alarm:<%= isAliveMessage %></b></p>
<% } %>
```

Comment: No this looks like JSP scriptlets, i.e. the _javascript_ tag is misplaced here ;)

Comment: What is the syntax error specifically?

Comment: Are you sure this is JavaScript? Sure it isn't Java or ASP?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ : Cool, It's corrected.

Comment: @demo.b Please think before editing. I'm reverting your edit.

Comment: _"it is showing syntax error with else token"_ could you specify what/who _it_ is? And is this the entire code or might there be something else that causes that error? The snippet itself looks fine to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Though it'd be nice to see a bit more code, I suppose you're using some templating engine like underscore and you probably have an error in the 5th line. Should be:

```
<% if (isAliveMessage=="TIVOLI ALARM") {%>
<FONT COLOR="Red">
<p><b>Status of Alarm:<%= isAliveMessage  %></b></p>
</FONT>
<% } else { %>
<p><b>Status of Alarm:<%= isAliveMessage %></b></p>
<% } %>
```

Basically you should put your *else* statement in the same line with closing bracket.

Comment: This is almost certainly server side, likely JSP, therefore very unlikely Underscore.js .